# c++ assignment deletes source of assigned value

Tags: c++, vector, variable-assignment

I have a class (simplified):

```
class a {
  private:
    std::vector<a> arguments;
  public:
    std::vector<a> getargs() { return arguments; }
};
```

Suppose, the class has a member function:

```
void a::bubble() {
  arguments = arguments[0].getargs();
}
```

Is this kosher (in that the source of the data, arguments[0], is deleted as a result of the command)?

It works on my compiler, but I just wanted to check if the c++ standard guarantees the safety of this operation.

Comment: You may want to look at return by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is ok.  The getargs() function is done before the assignment.  It creates a temporary that exists for the lifetime of the complete instruction statement (everything to ;).  That temporary is used in the call to the assignment operator for std::vector (works for raw types too though).  Everything is kosher and will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if you're copying a really large object? Say, one that can fit twice (once for the original, once for the copy) but not thrice? Or is the copy simply linked to the temporary? Cheers.

Comment: Well, you know what they say..."Size doesn't matter."  I supposed that some limit within `operator =` could cause an issue if we weren't talking about std::vector, but some 3rd party whatnot.  As far as the expression itself is concerned though, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it be legal?  Of course you will still go to the programmer's hell for this, but then again it's not really you, it's C++.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what do you want to do, but it should work fine. The only problem is that you must to be sure that you have at least 1 element in arguments.

Comment: For curiosity's sake, it's a parser for a lisp-like language. If a particular call has arity one, it simply replaces the call with its argument. No evaluation, as in lisp, so it's just a matter of bubbling the term up.